# How to get configuration options into my IdentityDBContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I try to leave my db context with only the default constructor but pass in the connection string in Startup.cs, I get an error 'AddDbContext was called with configuration, but the context type 'ApplicationDbContext' only declares a parameterless constructor'. If however I attempt to build it inside the DbContext itself via:

```
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ApplicationDbContext([FromServices]IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration["ConnectionString"]);
        }
```

there are complaints when used that "Could not create an instance of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor". If have both constructors, I unsurprisingly get a null reference exception when trying to access `_configuration`. I feel like this is a pretty common case, so I must be missing something obvious.

**Edit**

In startup.cs, this is how I'm adding the DbContext (in `ConfigureServices`):

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(/*options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString"])*/);
```

Also, the class is used in one other place in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>( options =>
            {...})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: Can you share the configuration section?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Comment: @fals of startup? any particular area you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a single constructor as follows:

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, [FromServices]IConfiguration configuration)
    : base(options)
{
}
```

Both arguments should be injected.

Comment: It does, but some part of the framework is demanding it have a default destructor, hence "Could not create an instance of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor"

Comment: Maybe you register `ApplicationDbContext` manually?
What part of the application throws the exception?

Comment: I believe it is registered manually (see original question edit). The call stack starts with: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'TimeZonesVue.ApplicationDbContext'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.CreateModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.<BindModelCoreAsync>d__4.MoveNext()

Comment: Does `ApplicationDbContext ` inherit `IdentityDbContext`?

Comment: it does - is that a problem?

Comment: No, it's exactly how it's defined in my project and it works well.